# httpclient got a "SSL certificate error" when post to https in glassfish servlet

Tags: java, maven, servlets, ssl, glassfish

I have write a  static post method with apache httpClient:

```
public class HttpPost {
    public static HttpPostResult post(String url, String xml) throws IOException {
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.INFO, url + "|" + xml);
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpPostResult httpPostResult = new HttpPostResult();
        PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(url);
        StringRequestEntity stringRequestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(xml,"xml","utf-8");
        postMethod.setRequestEntity(stringRequestEntity);
        httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
        httpPostResult.setStatus(postMethod.getStatusCode());
        httpPostResult.setResponseStr(postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());
        return httpPostResult;
    }
}
```

This method worked just fine when I test it stand-alone, but once I build it to a maven dependency and involve it in a http servlet, it just not  work and the response string become:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 The SSL certificate error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The SSL certificate error</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Seems remote host is using a nginx and I guess maybe there is some SSL trust issues occurred, but the remote host is trusted (with CA signed by trustful agency) it's `https://api.mch.weixin.qq.com/pay/orderquery`

What should be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by add some config in glassfish `domain.xml` with:

```
<jvm-options>-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit</jvm-options>
```

post this in case may be helpful to some one comes with same issue.

Note that `changeit` is the default password for glassfish keystore.